# Automatically ask router for port redirection on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, router, port-forwarding, dmz

Is there a way to use uPnp or something to automatically ask a router/firewall to redirect data coming from outside to a machine running ubuntu?

Here's the deal, I'm supposed to prepare a certain number of machines, which will act as kiosks, and they will be sent overseas; those who receive them are supposed to just plug in the ac and lan cable and nothing more. 
Now, I'm gonna need some ports open to control these machines (ssh), and I won't be there to configure their router. Who's gonna plug them in is going to be totally incompetent and wants to just plug them in and be ready and working.

I could also reformulate the question like this: when I'm running the no-ip daemon on it, I want THAT machine to answer, and not the router.

Thank you very much for your patience

Comment: Make sure your devices are IPv6 capable. This will eliminate this problem in future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is exactly what UPnP was designed for: client devices requesting specific port forwarding from the Internet router. You cannot rely, however, on a router supporting and being correctly configured for UPnP (and if you happen to be supplying the router as well, just be sure to pre-configure it for your needs).

What you'll be looking for to accomplish this is a UPnP *client* for Ubuntu; commonly, Ubuntu is used as a UPnP *server* when acting as a router to the rest of the network (this greatly diminished the quality of my Google results on the topic). UPnP is, however, basically a discovery protocol plus a SOAP-based web service; I found [a python script](https://gist.github.com/provegard/1435555) for a basic SSDP (the discovery protocol) client/server you may be able to adapt, and the SOAP stuff should be easy enough if you have a head for that kind of thing. There are SOAP libraries available for most scripting languages.

You may also find the [UPnP Specification](http://www.upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf) (1.1 MB Adobe PDF) useful.

The only other solution I can think of is to have the kiosk initiate the connection; perhaps you could have an area of the kiosk app that allows staff at the location to initiate a maintenance connection, causing the kiosk to contact your server. If it were me, that button would probably initiate some sort of VPN connection (like OpenVPN or L2TP/IPSec) to your server, establishing the network level link that you can then use to connect to the server in whatever manner you see fit. (Enacting the option could even require entering a "support code", which is actually the just-changed VPN user password.) Riffs on this solution include the kiosk permanently establishing a VPN connection, or establishing it for pre-defined "maintenance" windows. If you choose the automated option, I strongly recommend disclosing the practice to your clients—they may not take kindly to the idea if they discover it later (I know I wouldn't!).

Comment: If you decide to go the UPnP route, I suggest using a non-standard high port for the port-forward; this way, you'll not likely conflict with existing or future services at the same site.